# How to use "for" attribute in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a custom radio button in my project. The problem is this button will not work in a web form which is in a for loop. Because these use "for" attribute to select the unique id of the input field. But for my project I need these radio button to work in a foreach loop. I have tried doing it but can't find a solution.Is there is some way in javascript I can do this?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,900);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media (max-width: 40em) {
  .button-wrap {
    margin-top: -1.5em;
  }
}

.button-label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #292929;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  background: #efefef;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
.button-label h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin-top:10px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.button-label:hover {
  background: #d6d6d6;
  color: #101010;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
}
.button-label:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(2px);
          transform: translateY(2px);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}
@media (max-width: 40em) {
  .button-label {
    padding: 0em 1em 3px;
    margin: 0.25em;
  }
}

#yes-button:checked + .button-label {
  background: #2ECC71;
  color: #efefef;
}
#yes-button:checked + .button-label:hover {
  background: #29b765;
  color: #e2e2e2;
}


#no-button:checked + .button-label {
  background: #D91E18;
  color: #efefef;
}
#no-button:checked + .button-label:hover {
  background: #c21b15;
  color: #e2e2e2;
}



.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<body>
   <input class="hidden radio-label" type="radio" name="optradio" value="strongPositive"  id="yes-button"/>
   <label class="button-label" for="yes-button"><h1>option</h1></label>
  <input class="hidden radio-label" name="optradio" value="meduimPositive" type="radio"  id="no-button"/>
  <label class="button-label" for="no-button"><h1>option2</h1></label>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrap the radio with the label instead. `<label><input type="radio"> Text</input></label>`

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean by "work in a foreach loop". What does the non-working loop look like currently? What do you want it to do?

Comment: @apsillers The non-working loop looks like? I have a table in html and inside the table I have a button, when you click on the button you will get the above form. So because the table is in a PHP foreach loop and only the first row I am able to select those options. In the other row's I can't select those options

Comment: Because ids are unique in HTML, if you repeat id="yes-button" server-side, then every id will need a unique identifier. You could append a number, like id="yes-button0", id="yes-button1", id="yes-button2". Since you have CSS rules for yes-button and no-button, you should add yes-button and no-button as a class  (like class="hidden radio-label yes-button" and use .yes-button and .no-button selector.  The label's for attribute will be "yes-button0", "yes-button1", "yes-button2"

Comment: @progysm how can I generate label's for attribute unique every time. as for attributes only select an id in the element

Comment: it depends how you generate them and where the html code come from, using javascript you could check the number of lines, then concatene that number or use a global counter (increment it each time you add a row), or use a row number on the server.

Comment: To enable someone to answer pls [edit] your question to add your PHP and JavaScript. Also explain the purpose of the forms.

Comment: @dcorking I don't think so the purpose of the form is required for any question asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `id`s.  If you wrap the `<input>` in the `<label>`, the `<label>` will automatically associate to the `<input>`.

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="test" value="1"> Text 1</input></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="test" value="2"> Text 2</input></label>
```

See [MDN's `<label>` Usage Notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Usage_notes):

> - A `<label>` can be associated with a control either by placing the
>     control element inside the `<label>` element, or by using the for
>     attribute. Such a control is called the labeled control of the label
>     element. One input can be associated with multiple labels.

---

If you do find a reason that you absolutely **must have** an `id` (maybe additional aria attributes), I suggest that you create a static index variable that you increment and assign as you instantiate new instances of your widgets.  This is the pattern that I usually follow and is also the pattern that [Dojo](https://dojotoolkit.org/) follows.

Comment: Add a class for each background color?